# IPv4-mapped IPv6 address parsing

Tags: clickhouse

Does ch have some methods to convert IPv4-mapped IPv6 address looks like "::ffff:46.56.82.33" to IPv4?
I found only method for converting IPv4 into IPv4-mapped IPv6..
If not what I should use for its parsing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  reinterpret(
              reverse(
                 substr( IPv6StringToNum('::ffff:46.56.82.33'), 13, 4)
              ), 
        'IPv4') AS r;

┌─r───────────┐
│ 46.56.82.33 │
└─────────────┘
```

```
SELECT extract('::ffff:46.56.82.33', '\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$')


┌─extract('::ffff:46.56.82.33', '\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$')─┐
│ 46.56.82.33                                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. I'm not sure what your use case is but one option is to strip `::ffff:`

```sql
SELECT replaceOne('::ffff:46.56.82.33', '::ffff:', '');
```

(

```sql
SELECT toIPv4(replaceOne('::ffff:46.56.82.33', '::ffff:', ''));
```

)